# Display div above another one

Tags: html, css, css-position

I do have following divs:

```html
<div class="zoomTarget" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1050 !important; top: '.$y.'px; left: '.$x.'px;  height: 46px; width: 210px; border: none;">
  <div id="'.$id.'-1" class="rtop" style="z-index: 1050 !important; position: absolute !important; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;  height: '.$height1.'px; width: 200 px;">'.$gn1.'</div>
</div>
```

The outer div is a container, and contains a smaller div, fixed to the lower left edge of the container. This smaller div changes in size regularely. I would need to place another div inside the container that is anchored on top (certically above) the smaller div, so that when the div changes size it repositions accordingly.

I have tried to put a div inside the smaller div with relative position of y -20 but the div did not show up at all. It was somehow not visible.
how can this be done?

EDIT:

since the content of the smaller div will be programmaically updated in future, the other div cannot be inside the small div. it has to be outside the small div, and be somehow linked to the small one's top left edge

SAMPLE: DIV1 is anchored in the lower left corner of the parent and changes height. DIV2 should stay on top of DIV1 and move up and down according to the size of DIV1.

```
 ---------- 
|          |
|          |
| -------- |
||   DIV2 ||
| -------- |
| -------- |
||   DIV1 ||
| -------- |
 ----------
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, can you make an image or something else?

Comment: @skobaljic i tried to make a sketch.. hope it is clear now. please let me know.. thanks

Comment: have you looked at flexbox?

Comment: Why is the height of your containing parent element only `46px`?

Comment: thats a random number i wrote.. I do actaully have a variable there that changes too, but to simplify i used a random value

Answer (score 2):

According to the sketch, you need this kind of markup:

```css
.container-div {
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
}
.bottom-div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: orange;
}
.above-bottom-div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
    <div class="bottom-div">
        bottom
        <div class="above-bottom-div">
            above bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that is the goal. Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8z9q0spa/).